# Link to fanpage for facebook apps fb://page/Page_ID does not work and other questions about fb:// links

Tags: android, ios, hyperlink, qr-code, facebook-page

Here are some questions about fb:// links for iOS and android fb apps:

(1) Todav I created the link fb://page/PAGE_ID to a fanpage and than I created an qr code. What happened: I scanned the QR-Code with an iphone, the fb app opens but doesn't open the fanpage itself but only the wall of my own fb page. Strangest thing: A few days ago it worked correctly. But I downloaded a fb app update for ios yesterday, maybe there was a change on this point. Can anyone help me: Is the form of the link itself wrong? Is there another possibility to create a link to a fanpage which opens in the fb apps?

(2) If I already changed the URL of a facebook fanpage is there a possibility to create such a link with the name in place of the Site_ID? Would just look better for marketing purposes...

(3) A few days ago my test with the fb:// link an a iphone functioned. What happened: The fb app opens and the fanpage was shown. But unfortunately the "activity" site of the fanpage was opened. We would prefer if the "wall" site opens. Does anyone know, if it is possible to link directly to the "wall" with a link which will be open in fb apps?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be related to the Facebook API - it sounds like you were relying on undocumented behaviour of Facebook's iPhone app for your purposes, which is risky

Comment: Ok thanks for information. Didn't know that this kind of hyperlinks are relying on -undocumented behaviour- of Facebook's iPhone App. Regards!

Comment: There's a (now removed) answer suggesting that the `fb://profile/<PAGE ID>` format still works if that helps

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125780/custom-url-scheme-for-new-facebook-ios-app