# Custom URL scheme for new Facebook iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook

Does anyone know what the custom URL scheme is to open a Facebook page in their new iOS app. I was using fb://page/PAGE_ID however this doesn't seem to be working in the recently updated Facebook iOS app, it just opens the app but doesn't go to the required page.

Comment: http://handleopenurl.com/ provides info on tons of custom schemes. They refer you to http://iphonedevtools.com/?p=302 for fb scheme which has much info.

Answer (score 26):

I got this answer at [developer.facebook.com](http://developer.facebook.com):

Replace the word **page** with **profile** and it will work. Your new statement will be:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/247377102029332"]];
```

Comment: I had the same problem, and can confirm that this fix worked for me today.

Answer (score 18):

Use https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_USERNAME to get your page ID.

In your iOS app use: `fb://profile/[your ID]` and the facebook app will open to your page.

Answer (score 14):

The URL scheme for the iOS Facebook application is:

> fb://profile/(fbid)

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking along those lines. I'll try it and post back.

Comment: Seems this doesn't give a consistant experience across iOS devices. See above.

Comment: this worked perfectly for page. link should be like :  fb://profile/173781049448620

Answer (score 6):

Same problem here. fb://page/PAGE_ID is not working anymore. 
Note that fb://profile/(fbid) wasn't working properly on Facebook 4.x returning a "corrupted" page in both iPad and iPhone. Instead, fb://profile/(fbid)/**wall** in Facebook 4.x worked well when using an iPad but didn't work with an iPhone.

fb://page/PAGE_ID was the only option that worked on both iPhone and iPad, based on my experience.

I used to use http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes as reference, but it's currently down...

Comment: It's annoying that they don't document this. Well thinking I may just open safari rather than the app, as it seems this will give the most consistent experience across iPhone and iPad. Shame.

Comment: I tried using fb://page/{{PAGE_ID}} and it failed, but using fb://profile/{{PAGE_ID}} worked.

Comment: It worked for me too, but making action such as subscribing the page/liking it didn't work/wasn't available,
Have you managed doing any of the above?

Comment: @CoolAJ86 Do you got any work around to handle your issue. Actually in my case the fb url is received from our custom cms which is consumed for iOS and Android. For Android only page is working and for iOS only profile is working.

Answer (score -4):

A custom URL scheme is a mechanism through which third-party apps can communicate with each other. It doesn't allow you the provision to open a page in that particular application. It just fires an event to bring the called Application to the foreground. Going through [this documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50) would further clear your doubts.

The new Facebook app is built using Objective-C as against previous once in HTML5 which used to support URL scheme mechanism. [This link](http://techcrunch.com/2012/08/23/facebook-for-ios-faster/) gives a  hint on that.

http://techcrunch.com/2012/08/23/facebook-for-ios-faster/

Comment: Actually it does, or at least did. A Facebook fan page can be opened via a URL. Or at least it could before Facebook updated their app. Many apps have URL schemes available to do this kind of thing. Twitter for example has a URL scheme that allows the app to be opened and then a status or user profile to be displayed. Check this question for more info - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416338/open-a-facebook-link-by-native-facebook-app-on-ios

Comment: checkout similar problem solution http://alexandsoftware.blogspot.in/2012/05/ios-app-url-schema.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, some good information there, however it doesnt solve my problem. The link I described above was working for me before Facebook updated their iOS app. I'm trying to find out if the URL scheme has changed since then or if the ability to launch the app to a FB fan page has been removed.

Comment: I guess the new Facebook app is close to the iOS6 native Facebook integration app. So there might be some changes which would not allow the URL scheme mechanism

Comment: There have been changes yes. It's wrong to describe the FB iOS integration as an app though.