# Facebook button going to facebook iPhone app, but not loading correct facebook page

Tags: iphone, facebook, mobile-safari, uiapplication, openurl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom URL scheme for new Facebook iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125780/custom-url-scheme-for-new-facebook-ios-app)

I have a Facebook button in my iPhone app.  When it gets touched I want it to go to the Facebook iPhone app and load a facebook page if the Facebook iPhone app is on the device, if not, then go to Safari and go to this facebook page.  The code below takes you to the facebook app, but it just goes to the feed.  But it works how I want it to when the Facebook iphone app is not installed

This code does get run.

How can I go straight to the page from a click of the button?

```
NSString *urlStr = @"https://www.facebook.com/MYFACEBOOKPAGE";

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlStr];

if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url]) NSLog(@"%@%@",@"Failed to open url:",[url description]);
```

Comment: This answered my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125780/custom-url-scheme-for-new-facebook-ios-app

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using this instead.

`https://apps.facebook.com/YOUR-NAMESPACE-HERE`

I can access my own canvas app with the above URL, but using `www.` doesn't work.